# Inline element does not accept margin-top or bottom

Tags: html, css

Why the inline elements ignored margin top and bottom?
just accept margin right and left?

```
span {
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Comment: You can use `line-height` if you feel hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's inline. Inline elements cannot have any top and bottom margins (and also no top or bottom padding):

```css
span {
margin: 30px;
padding: 20px;
color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. <span>Donec pede justo,</span> fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a,
</p>
```

Comment: @KareemSultan sorry, I made that more precise and also added an example

Comment: Top and bottom padding work. They just don't affect the line height. Also, inline, non-replaced elements do have top and bottom margins. They just have no effect on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Inline, by definition, doesn't have top or bottom margin. What you'll want to use is `display: inline-block`. The height for `inline` is determined by the contained objects only.

Edit: Here's the [relevant spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced).